# How to add elements in the objects of my array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add elements in the objects of my array

```
data(){
  return{
    registro: [{a: "Hello world", b: "I don't guess that this will be read"}]
  }
}
methods:{
   Config(){
      var c = "otra variable de relleno"
      this.registro[0].push({c: "This is other text"});
   }
}
```

But when i execute that, drop this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this2.registro[0].push is not a function

Comment: See [MDN JavaScript Guide - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it it's like this:

```
this.registro[0] = Object.assign(this.registro[0], { c : "..." })
```

Comment: It would be simpler to use just `Object.assign(this.registro[0], { c : "..." })`. The `Object.assign` method mutates the targert object. No need to assign it to itself.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I put in this way so he can return the value as well if he prefers, like `return Object.assign(...)`. The best way to do it would actually be `Object.assign({}, ...)`. This way makes the code functional using the immutability concept by creating a new object and not mutating the original and creating side effects. I really appreciate the comment, let's keep in touch man :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `registro[0]` is not array, push will not work. Add the property to Object directly.

```
this.registro[0]['c'] = "This is other text";
```